# Access multiple elements of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a way to get array elements in one operation for known rows and columns of those elements? In each row I would like to access elements from col_start to col_end (each row has different starting and ending index). Number of elements is the same for each row, elements are consecutive.
Example:

```
[ . . . . | | | . . . . . ]
[ | | | . . . . . . . . . ]
[ . . | | | . . . . . . . ]
[ . . . . . . . . | | | . ]
```

One solution would be to get indexes (row-column pair) of elements, and than use my_array[row_list,col_list].

Is there any other (simpler) way without using for loops?

Comment: Yes, but can you provide a better example?

Comment: In the example ( | ) are elements I want to access, ( . ) are other elements. Would you like to know anything else?

Comment: @tjons: what convinces you that we are working with a dictionary?  The OP repeatedly refers to an array; the OP added the `numpy` tag; the representation looks a lot more like that of an array than a dictionary; etc.

Comment: @DSM my own confusedness. I'm wrong, and I've deleted the other comments. Thank you for pointing this out! On top of it, I didn't mean dictionary - I meant list. Whoops!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A = np.arange(40).reshape(4,10)*.1
startend = [[2,5],[3,6],[4,7],[5,8]]
index_list = [np.arange(v[0],v[1]) + i*A.shape[1] 
                 for i,v in enumerate(startend)]
# [array([2, 3, 4]), array([13, 14, 15]), array([24, 25, 26]), array([35, 36, 37])]
A.flat[index_list]
```

producing

```
array([[ 0.2,  0.3,  0.4],
       [ 1.3,  1.4,  1.5],
       [ 2.4,  2.5,  2.6],
       [ 3.5,  3.6,  3.7]])
```

This still has an iteration, but it's a rather basic one over a list. 
I'm indexing the flattened, 1d, version of `A`.  `np.take(A, index_list)` also works.

If the row intervals differ in size, I can use `np.r_` to concatenate them.  It's not absolutely necessary, but it is a convenience when building up indices from multiple intervals and values.

```
A.flat[np.r_[tuple(index_list)]]
# array([ 0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  2.4,  2.5,  2.6,  3.5,  3.6, 3.7])
```

---

The `idx` that `ajcr` uses can be used without `choose`:

```
idx = [np.arange(v[0], v[1]) for i,v in enumerate(startend)]
A[np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None], idx]
```

`idx` is like my `index_list` except that it doesn't add the row length.

```
np.array(idx)

array([[2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```

Since each `arange` has the same length, `idx` can be generated without iteration:

```
col_start = np.array([2,3,4,5])
idx = col_start[:,None] + np.arange(3)
```

The first index is a column array that broadcasts to match this `idx`.

```
np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None] 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

With this `A` and `idx` I get the following timings:

```
In [515]: timeit np.choose(idx,A.T[:,:,None])
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.8 µs per loop

In [516]: timeit A[np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None],idx]
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.8 µs per loop

In [517]: timeit A.flat[idx+np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None]*A.shape[1]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.9 µs per loop
```

The `flat` indexing is faster, but calculating the fancier index takes up some time.

For large arrays, the speed of `flat` indexing dominates.

```
A=np.arange(4000).reshape(40,100)*.1
col_start=np.arange(20,60)
idx=col_start[:,None]+np.arange(30)

In [536]: timeit A[np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None],idx]
10000 loops, best of 3: 108 µs per loop

In [537]: timeit A.flat[idx+np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None]*A.shape[1]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 59.4 µs per loop
```

The `np.choose` method runs into a hardcoded limit: `Need between 2 and (32) array objects (inclusive).`

---

What out of bounds `idx`?

```
col_start=np.array([2,4,6,8])
idx=col_start[:,None]+np.arange(3)
A[np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None], idx]
```

produces an error because the last `idx` value is `10`, too large.

You could `clip` `idx`

```
idx=idx.clip(0,A.shape[1]-1)
```

producing duplicate values in the last row

```
[ 3.8,  3.9,  3.9]
```

You could also pad `A` before indexing.  See `np.pad` for more options.

```
np.pad(A,((0,0),(0,2)),'edge')[np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None], idx]
```

Another option is to remove out of bounds values.  `idx` would then become a ragged list of lists (or array of lists).  The `flat` approach can handle this, though the result will not be a matrix.

```
startend = [[2,5],[4,7],[6,9],[8,10]]
index_list = [np.arange(v[0],v[1]) + i*A.shape[1] 
                 for i,v in enumerate(startend)]
# [array([2, 3, 4]), array([14, 15, 16]), array([26, 27, 28]), array([38, 39])]

A.flat[np.r_[tuple(index_list)]]
# array([ 0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6,  2.6,  2.7,  2.8,  3.8,  3.9])
```

Comment: Do you think using list comprehension will be faster than simply using a for loop?

Comment: For constant length ranges you don't need any iteration - just matrix addition.

Comment: I measured it myself and your method is faster indeed. Do you have any suggestions on how to prevent index out of bounds?

Comment: Out of bounds - like if a `col_start` value is too large, so `col_start+n>A.shape[1]`?  What should happen?

Comment: No, if col_start + n value is too large. I would like to "get" only elements that are in range - if A.shape[1] == 15 and col_start is 13, I would like to acquire only last two elements. If there is no "pretty" solution to this problem, I will use some sort of padding or some index checking and processing before acquiring array elements.

Comment: I added some examples of dealing with out-of-bounds.

Comment: Thanks, your answers are really helpful. Does anything simplifies if size of second axis for idx is 1? After accessing those elements in matrix A and some calculations I get indexes for another array. I would like to get elements of that matrix as 1D array or a list. Any ideas? (That is my last question, I promise :) )

Comment: Off hand I'm not following you last question.  Can you start a new question with some more detail?

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use it, but I didn't get the desired output, because of this: [:,None]. It works fine now that I removed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.choose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html).

Here's an example NumPy array `arr`:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]])
```

Let's say we want to pick the values `[1, 2, 3]` from the first row, `[11, 12, 13]` from the second row and `[17, 18, 19]` from the third row.

In other words, we'll pick out the indices from each row of `arr` as shown in an  array `idx`:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Then using `np.choose`:

```
>>> np.choose(idx, arr.T[:,:,np.newaxis])
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [11, 12, 13],
       [17, 18, 19]])
```

---

To explain what just happened: `arr.T[:,:,np.newaxis]` meant that `arr` was temporarily viewed as 3D array with shape `(7, 3, 1)`. You can imagine this as 3D array where each column of the original `arr` is now a 2D column vector with three values. The 3D array looks a bit like this:

```
#  0       1       2       3       4       5       6
[[ 0]   [[ 1]   [[ 2]   [[ 3]   [[ 4]   [[ 5]   [[ 6]   # choose values from 1, 2, 3
 [ 7]    [ 8]    [ 9]    [10]    [11]    [12]    [13]   # choose values from 4, 5, 6
 [14]]   [15]]   [16]]   [17]]   [18]]   [19]]   [20]]  # choose values from 3, 4, 5
```

To get the *zeroth* row of the output array, `choose` selects the *zeroth* element from the 2D column at index `1`, the *zeroth* element from the 2D column at index `2`, and the *zeroth* element from the 2D column at index `3`.

To get the *first* row of the output array, `choose` selects the *first* element from the 2D column at index `4`, the *first* element from the 2D column at index `5`, ... and so on.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I was thinking of. Now I have to check the performance of given solutions.

Comment: I have one more question. What is the best way to create idx array if I have col_start vector and col_end vector equals (col_start + n)?

Comment: @soccersniper: one way could be to use `np.vstack` and a list comprehension, e.g. `np.vstack([np.arange(x, x+n) for x in col_start])`. So above in my example, `n` is `3` and `col_start` is `[1, 4, 3]`.

Comment: Because n << len(col_start) I would rather do this: np.array( [col_start+i for i in range(n)] ) (same result if I use np.vstack). I would have to transpose this array to use your solution. Is there any other way?

Comment: It is possible to index `arr` with `idx` without `choose` - just use a matching column array for the 1st dimension.

Comment: I added `idx = col_start[:,None] + np.arange(3)` to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like the below. I'm not sure what you want to do with them when you access them though.

```
indexes = [(4,6), (0,2), (2,4), (8, 10)]
arr = [
    [ . . . . | | | . . . . . ],
    [ | | | . . . . . . . . . ],
    [ . . | | | . . . . . . . ],
    [ . . . . . . . . | | | . ]
]

for x in zip(indexes, arr):
    index = x[0]
    row = x[1]
    print row[index[0]:index[1]+1]
```

Comment: only problem is you now don't have a numpy array

Comment: I want to find max value for "masked" elements in each row. Solution for accessing those elements would be simple if columns would be the same for all rows: my_array[:,col_start:col_end]. What I was looking for was a modification of previous statement in the case of different column indexes.

Comment: Where is numpy array coming from? OP says nothing about that? And @tjons: nothing in my answer is a dictionary?

Comment: Original array contains dot products between direction vectors and gradient vectors on "rays" pointing from the center outwards for given angles. So i-th row of dot_product array contains dot products along the "ray" for i-th angle.

Comment: @mattm my own confusedness. I'm wrong, and I've deleted the other comments. Thank you for pointing this out! On top of it, I didn't mean dictionary - I meant list. Whoops!