# Is there a more efficient way to slice a multi dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I noticed that indexing a multi dimensional array takes more time than indexing a single dimensional array

```
a1 = np.arange(1000000)
a2 = np.arange(1000000).reshape(1000, 1000)
a3 = np.arange(1000000).reshape(100, 100, 100)
```

When I index `a1`

```
%%timeit
a1[500000]
```

> The slowest run took 39.17 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
>   10000000 loops, best of 3: 84.6 ns per loop

```
%%timeit
a2[500, 0]
```

> The slowest run took 31.85 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
>   10000000 loops, best of 3: 102 ns per loop

```
%%timeit
a3[50, 0, 0]
```

> The slowest run took 46.72 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
>   10000000 loops, best of 3: 119 ns per loop

---

At what point should I consider an alternative way to index or slice a multi-dimensional array?  What are the circumstances that make it worth the effort and loss of transparency?

Comment: You are talking more about indexing individual items, not slices (`:`).  Indexing on the flat version is faster - but by a factor less that 2?  Is the speed gain worth the loss in clarity?  Should you even be indexing a single item?

Comment: @hpaulj it was me noticing this that led me to wondering "Under what circumstances would it be worth while to flatten an array and index or slice?"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005531/access-multiple-elements-of-an-array - selecting several items from each row of 2d array.  I found that `flat` indexing was faster, but had to be balanced against the higher cost of calculating the index.  Basically the same sort of pattern - flat is better when the arrays get larger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One alternative to slicing an `(n, m)` array is to flatten the array and derive what it's one dimensional position must be.

consider `a = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])`
we can get the 2nd row, 3rd column with `a[1, 2]` and get `5`
or we can calculate that `1 * a.shape[1] + 2` is the one dimensional position if we flatten `a` with `order='C'`
thus we can perform the equivalent slice with `a.ravel()[1 * a.shape[1] + 2]`

Is this efficient?  No, for indexing a single number from an array, it isn't worth the trouble.

What about if we want to slice many numbers from the array?  I devised the following test for a 2-D array

---

***2-D test***

```
from timeit import timeit

n, m = 10000, 10000
a = np.random.rand(n, m)
r = pd.DataFrame(index=np.power(10, np.arange(7)), columns=['Multi', 'Flat'])

for k in r.index:
    b = np.random.randint(n, size=k)
    c = np.random.randint(m, size=k)
    kw = dict(setup='from __main__ import a, b, c', number=100)
    r.loc[k, 'Multi'] = timeit('a[b, c]', **kw)
    r.loc[k, 'Flat'] = timeit('a.ravel()[b * a.shape[1] + c]', **kw)

r.div(r.sum(1), 0).plot.bar()
```

[image]

It appears that when slicing more than 100,000 numbers, it's better to flatten the array.

---

What about `3-D`
***3-D test***

```
from timeit import timeit

l, n, m = 1000, 1000, 1000
a = np.random.rand(l, n, m)
r = pd.DataFrame(index=np.power(10, np.arange(7)), columns=['Multi', 'Flat'])

for k in r.index:
    b = np.random.randint(l, size=k)
    c = np.random.randint(m, size=k)
    d = np.random.randint(n, size=k)

    kw = dict(setup='from __main__ import a, b, c, d', number=100)
    r.loc[k, 'Multi'] = timeit('a[b, c, d]', **kw)
    r.loc[k, 'Flat'] = timeit('a.ravel()[b * a.shape[1] * a.shape[2] + c * a.shape[1] + d]', **kw)

r.div(r.sum(1), 0).plot.bar()
```

[image]

Similar results, maybe more dramatic.

***Conclusion***
For 2 dimensional arrays, consider flattening and deriving flatten positions if you need to pull more than 100,000 elements from the array.

For 3 or more dimensions, it seems clear that flattening the array is almost always better.

---

***Criticism is welcome***
Did I do something wrong?  Did I not think of something obvious?

Comment: After a quick glance, the calculations look good. Interesting that the speed advantage remains constant. I suppose there could be some use cases for this.